# Is it possible to move text from one world file into another to save a corrupted world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My world seems to be corrupt. I had built some large structures that I cannot build again. Can you take some of the text in the files of a world and put it in another world? That way, when you play the new world you have the things that you copied from the other world?

I have tried to copy some files in to another world but the world crashed.  I am not good at code, and I have tried searching but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! What do you mean with corrupt? Were you using mods? You should contact Mojang support, there's not much we can do to help you, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new world with the same seed and exchanging the file "level.dat" in its world folder, then try to open your old world again.